# yii activeform label translation from different translation-file

Tags: php, yii, active-form

I need to translate a label of an active form without changing the model.

This:

```
$form->label($model, 'myField', array('class' => 'title'))
```

Takes the translation by default from the translation.php in the protected/messages/lang/ folder.

Now I want the label to take the translation from another file (without changing the model).
How would I do that? The docs are a little vague on what kind of variables I can pass to the label...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `label` in the `$htmlOptions` array:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeLabel-detail

```
$form->label(
  $model, 
  'myField', 
  array('class' => 'title', 'label' => Yii::t('myCategory', 'Field label'))
)
```

`Yii::t()` method translates the given message from source language to target language. You can read more information about internationalization here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#t-detail
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

Comment: Thanks a ton! I couldn't find that in the docs - maybe I'm just a little blind...